# WPF Datagrid perform action when row is selected with data associated with that row

Tags: c#, wpf

Got a list of objects which is currently being displayed via a datagrid.  What I need to do is when a user double clicks on a specified row it opens up another window which is a model showing the data associated with the object of the row that is currently selected.  I can't figure out how to a) detect when the user double clicks and b) how to know which row the user double clicked on.

The XAML:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="BlueprintsDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Game.Blueprints, ElementName=uc}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="80*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ME" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding MaterialEfficiency}"
                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRightJustify}"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource ColumnRight}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="BPO" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding IsOrginial}"
                                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRightJustify}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BlueprintsDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Game.Blueprints, ElementName=uc}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelection}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="80*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ME" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding MaterialEfficiency}"
                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRightJustify}"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource ColumnRight}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="BPO" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding IsOrginial}"
                                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRightJustify}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Note:** *CurrentSelection* must exist in your ViewModel-class. This property has to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and must be the type of object your *ItemsSource* is holding!

For recognizing the mouse double click you can extend the above xaml to something like

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="BlueprintsDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Game.Blueprints, ElementName=uc}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelection}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleClickedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="80*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ME" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding MaterialEfficiency}"
                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRightJustify}"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource ColumnRight}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="BPO" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding IsOrginial}"
                                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRightJustify}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Note:** You therefore need a property DoubleClickedCommand of the type ICommand in your ViewModel. There you can check for your CurrentSelection.

```
public ICommand DoubleClickedCommand { get; set; }
```

In your ViewModel constructor:

```
DoubleClickedCommand = new RelayCommand(DoubleClick);
```

And the method itself:

```
private void DoubleClick()
{
    if(CurrentSelection == null) { return; }
    // Do stuff in here            
}
```

Comment: what is i:?  Interaction.Triggers looks to be in System.Windows.Interactivity, but that's not available in my list of assemblies....

Comment: Sorry. The namespace has to be _xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"_

Comment: also, in the ctor you have DoubleClickedCommand = new RelayCommand(....).  What is RelayCommand?

Comment: RelayCommand implements the ICommand interface and it comes from using _GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;_ I'm using the MVVMLight package in my project. If you are not using this package you have to implement your own version of ICommand.

Comment: Sorry, your example doesn't work.  I copied the implementation for RelayCommand, but the ctor assignment gives me compile error Generic type RelayCommand<T> requires 1 type arguments....

Comment: You could implement your own version of RelayCommand. It's not too hard. You just need to implement an event for when CanExecute changes and two methods, CanExecute and Execute itself...

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `MouseDoubleClick` event and cast the `DataContext` of the source of the event:

```
private void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var fe = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
    if (fe != null)
    {
        var blueprint = fe.DataContext as BluePrint;
        if (blueprint != null)
        {
            //open window...
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BlueprintsDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Game.Blueprints, ElementName=uc}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          MouseDoubleClick="Dgm_MouseDoubleClick">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="80*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ME" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding MaterialEfficiency}"
                            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRightJustify}"
                            CellStyle="{StaticResource ColumnRight}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="BPO" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding IsOrginial}"
                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRightJustify}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Change BluePrint to whatever the name of your class is.